# Avro schema not conforming to my json data?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, schema, avro, confluent-platform

I am producing a json message and trying to make it avro compliant. Here is an example of the message I want to send but i am getting the following error I think this is due to the schema not matching the data but could be wrong, I am using the KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName() for the value serializer

`nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message`

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of string of com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.CoveragesPreviousPolicy of com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.VehiclesPreviousPolicy of array of com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.previous_policy of com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.PolicyAvro of com.lm.gde.eventing.avro.EnrichedPolicyEventAvro`

```
{
    "eventType": "policy.PolicyTxIssueEvent",
    "correlationId": "XXXXXX",
    "timestamp": 1572532310225,
    "policy": {
        "policyNumber": "XXXXXX",
        "policyId": "XXXXXX",
        "customerNumber": "XXXXXX",
        "effectiveDate": "2019-10-26T00:00:00+01:00",
        "expirationDate": "2020-10-25T23:59:00Z",
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2019-10-31T00:00:00Z",
        "revisionNumber": "2",
        "policyStatusCd": "issued",
        "previousPolicyVersionId": "XXXXXX",
        "transactionTypeCd": "endorsement",
        "vehicles": [{
            "registrationNo": "XXXXXX",
            "make": "XXXXXX",
            "model": "XXXXXX",
            "coverages": {
                "roadAssistanceCoverLevelCd": "Medium"
            }
        }],
        "customer": {
            "extensionFields": {
                "nif": "XXXXXX"
            },
            "individualDetails": {
                "firstName": "XXXXXX",
                "lastName": "XXXXXX"
            },
            "phones": [{
                "phoneNumber": "XXXXXX"
            }],
            "addresses": [{
                "addressLine1": "XXXXXX",
                "addressLine2": "",
                "addressLine3": "",
                "city": "XXXXXX",
                "postalCode": "XXXXXX"
            }]
        },
        "previous_policy": {
            "vehicles": [{
                "registrationNo": "XXXXXX",
                "coverages": {
                    "roadAssistanceCoverLevelCd": null
                }
            }],
            "policyNumber": "XXXXXX",
            "policyId": "XXXXXX",
            "customerNumber": "XXXXXX",
            "effectiveDate": "2019-10-26T00:00:00+01:00",
            "expirationDate": "2020-10-25T23:59:00Z",
            "transactionEffectiveDate": "2019-10-26T00:00:00+01:00",
            "policyStatusCd": "issued",
            "transactionTypeCd": "policy",
            "revisionNumber": "1",
            "previousPolicyVersionId": null
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the schema I wrote

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.lm.gde.eventing.avro",
    "name": "EnrichedPolicyEventAvro",
    "version": "1",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "eventType",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "correlationId",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "policy",
            "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "PolicyAvro",
                "fields": [{
                        "name": "policyNumber",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "policyId",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "customerNumber",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "effectiveDate",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "expirationDate",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "transactionEffectiveDate",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "revisionNumber",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "policyStatusCd",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "previousPolicyVersionId",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "transactionTypeCd",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "vehicles",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "array",

                            "items": {
                            "name": "vehicles",
                            "type": "record",
                            "fields":[
                                {
                                    "name": "registrationNo",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "make",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "model",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "coverages",
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "record",
                                        "name": "coverages",
                                        "fields": [{
                                            "name": "roadAssistanceCoverLevelCd",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "customer",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "record",
                            "name": "customer",
                            "fields": [{
                                    "name": "extensionFields",
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "record",
                                        "name": "extensionFields",
                                        "fields": [{
                                            "name": "nif",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "individualDetails",
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "record",
                                        "name": "individualDetails",
                                        "fields": [{
                                                "name": "firstName",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "lastName",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "phones",
                                    "type": {

                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "name": "phoneNumber",
                                            "type": "record",
                                            "fields":[
                                            {
                                                "name": "phoneNumber",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                            ]
                                        }

                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "addresses",
                                    "type": {

                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "name": "address",
                                            "type": "record",
                                            "fields":[
                                            {
                                                "name": "addressLine1",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "addressLine2",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "addressLine3",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "city",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "postalCode",
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                            ]
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "previous_policy",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "record",
                            "name": "previous_policy",
                            "fields": [{
                                    "name": "vehicles",
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                        "name": "VehiclesPreviousPolicy",
                                        "type": "record",
                                        "fields": [{
                                                "name": "registrationNo",
                                                "type": "string"

                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "coverages",
                                                "type": {
                                                    "type": "record",
                                                    "name": "CoveragesPreviousPolicy",
                                                    "fields": [{
                                                        "name": "roadAssistanceCoverLevelCd",
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            }

                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "policyNumber",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "policyId",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "customerNumber",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "effectiveDate",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "expirationDate",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "transactionEffectiveDate",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "policyStatusCd",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "transactionTypeCd",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "revisionNumber",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "previousPolicyVersionId",
                                    "type": "string"
                                }



                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the schema by posting the data in an online converter here https://toolslick.com/generation/metadata/avro-schema-from-json